# What weights should I use to start a NEAT based neural network?

Tags: neural-network

After reading a few papers on Neuro Evolution, more specifically NEAT, I realised that there was very little information regarding how you should weight each synapse at the start of the Neural Network. I understand that at the start, using NEAT, all the input neurons are connected to the output neuron, and then evolution takes place from there. However, should you weight each synapse randomly at the start, or simply set each one to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter a lot - it matters most how you mutate the weights of the connections in a genome.

However, setting the weights of each genome's connections to a random value is best: it acts like a small random search in the 'right' direction. If you'd set all the weights the same in for each genome, then weights in genomes will be extremely similar: keep in mind that a genome has a lot of connections, and with a mutation rate of `0.3` and two mutation options for example, only `15%` of the population will have at least óne different weight after just 1 generation.

So make it something random, like `random() * .2 - .1` (distribute between `[-0.1, 0.1]`). Just figure out what values work best for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying!